# notify_url is not reached or may be false response in sandbox paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am applying a paypal checkout process in my website.In which i want to update database after the successful payment.I have given the correct notify_url but this url never been called but i have reached at a successful payment in Sandbox Paypal.I have put a email address to check whether the function upadatePayments() is called or not but getting no mail after the paypal response.

The code i am using is below:-

index.html

```
<form class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form" target="_blank">    
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Ankush"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Kalia"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="a1p_ramesh@yahoo.com"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="6789" / >
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit Payment"/>
</form>
```

payments.php

```
<?php
// Database variables
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "amarhost_mypay"; //database username
$pass = "problem_12345"; //database password
$db_name = "amarhost_paypal_ipn"; //database name

// PayPal settings
$paypal_email = 'akaash_1351258109_biz@gmail.com';
$return_url = 'http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/paypal2/payment-successful.htm';
$cancel_url = 'http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/paypal2/payment-cancelled.htm';
$notify_url = 'http://50.116.97.120/~amarhost/paypal2/payments.php';

$item_name = 'Test Item';
$item_amount = 5.00;

// Include Functions
include("functions.php");

//Database Connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Check if paypal request or response
if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])){

    // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
        $querystring .= "?notify_url=".urlencode($notify_url)."&";
    $querystring .= "business=".urlencode($paypal_email)."&";


    // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

    //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
    $querystring .= "item_name=".urlencode($item_name)."&";
    $querystring .= "amount=".urlencode($item_amount)."&";

    //loop for posted values and append to querystring
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
    }

    // Append paypal return addresses
    $querystring .= "return=".urlencode(stripslashes($return_url))."&";
    $querystring .= "cancel_return=".urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url));

    // Append querystring with custom field
    //$querystring .= "&custom=".'123';

    // Redirect to paypal IPN
    header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
    exit();

}else{

    // Response from Paypal

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);// IPN fix
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']          = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']        = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']     = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']     = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency']   = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']             = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']     = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']        = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']             = $_POST['custom'];

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    } else {    

        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Verified Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");

                // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                if($valid_txnid && $valid_price){
                                        $to = "a1p_ramesh@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);               
                    $orderid = updatePayments($data);       
                    if($orderid){                   
                        // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database                              
                    }else{                              
                        // Error inserting into DB
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                    }
                }else{                  
                    // Payment made but data has been changed
                    // E-mail admin or alert user
                }                       

            }else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
                // E-mail admin or alert user

                // Used for debugging
                //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
            }       
        }       
    fclose ($fp);
    }   
}
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
// functions.php
function check_txnid($tnxid){
    global $link;
    return true;
    $valid_txnid = true;
    //get result set
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE txnid = '$tnxid'", $link);       
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $valid_txnid = false;
    }
    return $valid_txnid;
}

function check_price($price, $id){
    $valid_price = false;
    //you could use the below to check whether the correct price has been paid for the product

    /* 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM `products` WHERE id = '$id'");       
    if (mysql_numrows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $num = (float)$row['amount'];
            if($num == $price){
                $valid_price = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $valid_price;
    */
    return true;
}

function updatePayments($data){ 
    global $link;
    if(is_array($data)){                
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_amount']."' ,
                '".$data['payment_status']."' ,
                '".$data['item_number']."' ,
                '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' 
                )", $link);
    return mysql_insert_id($link);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log into the akaash_1351258109_biz@gmail.com account (under www.sandbox.paypal.com),
Go to the account settings, profile , instant payment notification settings

(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify)

And make sure that this is enabled.

PayPal automatically turns it off after repeated failures, and that disables *all* IPN's for the account, regardless of whether you specified it in the API call.

Comment: i have set ipn settings for the account but sill having no response

Comment: i have used this source for paypal integration  http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration can you check what is wrong i am reaching to successful payment but values are not inserting in database.

Comment: Try using the IPN simulator to debug your API call.
This sends a message directly to the URL of your choice, from PayPal servers. That way you can rule out connectivity issues, such as your site being unreachable for PayPal, or also that your IPN handler is not working as intended.

https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session