# Paypal Sandbox IPN always fails

Tags: grails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm developing a grails app using http://grails.org/plugin/paypal plugin.
I've followed all instructions, configured my app to work with a dyndns (no-ip).

I can access my app from outside my network.
All the payment is correct, if I click on the "back to test's store" link it returns to my site.

The problem is that no IPN are sent to my IPN handler.

In the IPN history I can see all transactions in error state, but no http response code is shown.

It retries 8 times each message.

Notification URL is correct.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself,

looks like paypal does not send IPN posts to URL with ports other than 80 or 443

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?  I've been having this problem and was just told by a paypal integration specialist that a nonstandard port should not be a problem.

Comment: I've not found documentation, I can only tell you about my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the troubleshooting steps I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965).  These may help.