# PayPal IPN Nightmares

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have setup an IPN listener. I throw this a test IPN from PayPal Developer - it says it's been sent successfully but then doesnt appear in ANY IPN history page... so I can't see if it's working or not.

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the IPN on a test sandbox seller account, and go through and make test payment with your sandbox buyer account.  Then you should be able to log into the test sandbox seller account and see the IPN history and see if it is being sent out and what status code is being returned.  Also, there are some [troubleshooting tips posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965) that may help to resolve the issue as well depending on what is specifically happening after further investigation.