# Delivery status SENT but no IPN responce

Tags: paypal-ipn

I configured IPN listener and enable auto-respond by using URL. i test using  IPN simulator it runs perfectly but auto respond is not working properly. IPN History given proper details but DB not changed.

Details are:

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) details

Message ID20A455865K857272G

Date/time created4/17/2013 04:25 PDT

Original/ResentOriginal

Latest delivery attempt date/time4/17/2013 04:25 PDT

Notification URLhttp://testdomain.com/pwo_dev/index.php/user/PaypalIPN

HTTP response code 200

Delivery statusSent

No. of retries0

Transaction ID77S48208XN775144R

IPN typeTransaction made
[image]

But when i resending same IPN then it is working fine.

Please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your server's access log to see if PayPal is actually hitting your script, or checked your error logs to see if any errors are being generated.  First you need to determine if you are actually getting the data sent to your system.  Then once you have determined that you need, to determine why your script is not working.  The error logs can help with this.  You can also try adding some debug lines to your code so that you can step through it and see where it is failing at.  There are also some [IPN Troubleshooting Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965) here that may help as well.  If want to verify that it is a script issue and not a server issue, try using a simplified version of an IPN script.  Have it just send you an email, or write something to text file.  You can also find some of PayPal's [IPN scripts here](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623) that may help, and give you a working example to test with.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked access log file it gives given message. `code`173.0.82.126 - - [18/Apr/2013:13:51:47 +0000] "POST /pwo_dev/index.php/user/PaypalIPN HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"'code' My script running perfectly when i am resending IPN from IPN history.

Comment: Then if you know the IPN is being sent, and your server is responding correctly.  You would need to review the script and see what is causing the error and the DB not to be updated.

Comment: My script running properly and my DB being updated but in only resend IPN condition.

Comment: When checking your server logs, are you seeing the PayPal system hitting your script only for the resend or for the initial post?  If  you are not seeing anything hit your server for the initial post, I would suggest opening up a ticket with MTS at www.paypal.com/mts so that we can look into this further.  Be sure to provide specific details, and examples as well so that we can check our logs against the examples.