# Paypal recurring payment IPN usage

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I successfully create a listener and it is working well if I am using the IPN simulator. However, when I am doing the payment request in the process of payment, I set the same listener url for the notify_url, nothing happens even the process working properly. How can I know if someone cancel his recurring payment directly from the Paypal or how do I setup up the listener whenever a recurring payment is made? Is it something wrong with my notify_url? This is what my notify_url look like:

> http://example.com/paypal_notification/ipn_callback

No extra parameters. Is it correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting an IPN when the profile is created, each time the recurring profile bills, and when the profile is cancelled.  Check your IPN history in your account to make sure the IPN's are being sent out, and check to see if there is any type of error being returned to PayPal.  Check your server access logs to see PayPal is calling your script and check your error logs to see if anything is being triggered.  Try adding www. to your URL, and the ext to the end of your URL for the type of file it is.  Also, there are some [IPN troubleshooting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965) I posted for IPN on this [forum POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965).

Comment: Thank you. I checked the IPN setting in my account and realized I didn't turn it on. After I activated it, everything's ok now. However I still have a question as in my project, I have many sellers and payers. The sellers can be payers too. I can't ask them to turn on IPN from their own account one by one, how can I make sure their payment is made or cancelled in every transaction, I mean how to monitor this. I made some tests on this but no IPN is received except those IPN is on. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The IPN will only be sent to the account on which the profile was created. 
Here's how I would do it.

1. Store the Paypal ProfileID and e-mail address in a database.
2. Receive all of the IPN notifications yourself, and in the case of a failure, send an e-mail to the specific user based on their ProfileID, or perform other actions.

Comment: My case is I have many payers and sellers in my project. Payers can be sellers too. So when a payer subscribe from a seller, I will insert the notify_url when I am creating the profile. In case the payer cancels his payment from PayPal, I can receive whatever message that came from PayPal. However if the sellers or payers do not turn on their IPN, I can't do much until the seller complains he didn't receive the payment. Any better solution? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you're right, you will have to tell them to turn on their own IPN inside of PayPal, and provide them with an IPN file.

Comment: To end users it's kinda difficult to set the IPN because paypal UI is very complicated....

Comment: It's the only way man, either they do that, or they don't get the IPN response... Maybe PayPal isn't the best solution :(