# PayPal IPN Won't Do Anything

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been trying to figure out for the past 12 hours as to why this isn't working. I have found the most recent and updated code that everyone should now be using with the IPN system. In case you are unsure as to why the POST header is now **HTTP/1.1** instead of **HTTP/1.0**, look here:
https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ipn-and-pdt-scripts-and-http-1-1

In any block of this script, a message should be placed in log.txt, but that doesn't even happen.

Any insight anyone can provide would be awesome:

```
<?php 

  //read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
  }

  //post back to PayPal system to validate (replaces old headers)
  $header .="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
  $header .="Connection: close\r\n";

  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
  //

  //error connecting to paypal
  if (!$fp) {
    file_put_contents('log.txt', 'httperror');
  }

  //successful connection    
  if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
      $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
      $res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT

      if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        if ($_POST["payment_status"] == "Completed") {
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "removedforsecurity", "removedforsecurity", "removedforsecurity");
          if (!$link) {
            printf("Can't connect to localhost. Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
          }

          $username = $_POST["custom"];
          $date = date('Y-m-d');

          /* update rows */
          mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET access='user' WHERE username='myusername'");

          file_put_contents('log.txt', 'veri');
          /* close connection */
          mysqli_close($link);
        }
      }

      if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'failed');
      }
    }
    fclose($fp);
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these [IPN Troubleshooting Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778567/notify-url-never-call-when-buyer-paid-for-subscription/15788965#15788965).  These may help.  Also check your IPN history in your PayPal account to make sure that the IPN is actually being sent out.  It should also show if it was sent successfully, or if it failed and is retrying.  There should also be a status code of what your server is returing within the details of the IPN history message.  PayPal expects a 200ok response.